# Load data from file using SF2 Yaml component

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

In my project am trying to use Symfony2 YAML component.
I create directory config and with factory pattern. I try to optimize that component to work on my project. I expect to read and write(dump) config files.

I succeed to read and dump config files. But how can I read only one line from config?

#### Example:

In my `parameters.yml` file, I save database (doctrine) data for connecting to a DB.

So how to read just `HOST` or just `Password`?

All time when I dump array, I get full result of content:

```
doctrine: dbal: { driver: pdo_mysql, host: localhost, port: null, dbname: posteri, user: root, password: 123123, charset: UTF }
```

The method I use is:

```
public static function readYaml($file, $path = "config/", $ext = '.yml')
{
    if (!self::$yaml)
    {
        $filename = BASEPATH . $path . $file . $ext ;

        self::$yaml = new Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml();

        try
        {
            $value = self::$yaml->parse(file_get_contents($filename));
        }
        catch (ParseException $e)
        {
            printf("Unable to parse the YAML string: %s", $e->getMessage());
        }

        return self::$yaml->dump($value);
    }
}


// Debug
$config  = Factory::readYaml('parameter');


print_r($config);
```

Do I need to install Config component from SF2 and implement file locator for this job?

I expect from this component only to read one line of config file.

Comment: I think when i read that YAML file that return array.